# Why do those pointer deferences lead to different results?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

Let's say I have some `typedef struct {int b;} some_t;` and a pointer `a` to such a struct. Then why is

```
(*a).b = 5;
```

not the same as

```
some_t c = *a;
c.b = 5;
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second, `c` is a *copy* of `*a`, and `c.b` is a copy of `(*a).b`.

`c.b = 5` modifies the copy, not the original.

Comment: How appropriate to choose 'c' as name then. ;-) All clear now, thanks!

Comment: I think you mean c.b is equivalent to (*a).b, not a copy.

Comment: @Daniel: No, it's a copy of the value.

Comment: But (*a).b != c.b, but it has the same behavior in terms of element access... where as I read your statement as the opposite, hence the statements are equivalent, though to structs at different addresses.
Bah, English semantics...